# Best way to handle frequent grid data updates from WebSocket in Angular app

Tags: angular, websocket, ag-grid, web-worker, ag-grid-angular

My website is built with Angular 10 and uses ag-grid to display multiple grids with 1000s of rows. Each grid receives frequent updates to its row data via websocket connection. The update objects have to be processed against the existing grid data to determine if it's a row that should be added, deleted, or updated.

Currently, this processing is causing huge performance problems, with grids freezing and page becoming unresponsive.

My question is: what is the best way to handle this? Would putting the websocket in a webworker help? Would it make sense to do so if the webworker would also need to know the grids' full dataset to process the updates against existing data? Are there other potential solutions to this?

Comment: Have you checked (implemented) what is in the docs: https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-grid/data-update-high-frequency/

Comment: It is too difficult to provide an answer because there is a lot of information missing. Does the websocket only return one or more rows? How often ? Do you develop on the backend or just on the frontend? What method do you use to update the grid? In fact it would take code snippets I think because it is possible to intervene in many places ...

Comment: How are you displaying your 1000s of rows? Are you making use of some sort of virtual scrolling to avoid rendering performance issues. I would also recommend using a track by function for the ngFor loop if you’re using one. This provides a component reuse strategy to avoid redundant rendering work. I would also recommend using an onPush change detection strategy.